# Choose delimiters in the command according the case

Tags: math-mode, macros, delimiters, physics

I'm trying to create a similar command as `\qty` from `physics package`. To understand, I have the following code as example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{physics}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\grad}{sm}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\nabla#2}
    {\nabla\biggl[ #2 \biggl]}
}

\begin{document}

The command $\backslash\text{qty}$ produces
\begin{gather*}
    \qty(x+y), \qquad
    \qty[x+y], \qquad
    \qty{x+y}
\end{gather*}
All I have now is the command $\backslash\text{grad}$ that only accepts braces \{\}:
\begin{gather*}
    \grad{x+y}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

The command I want to adapt is this `\grad` to be able to write: `\grad()`, `\grad[]` or `\grad{}`.

Comment: It would be helpful to post a minimal document that shows this command in its regular use. Is this the one defined by `physics` as well?

Comment: done! Yes, it's the same provided by `physics`

Comment: If it should behave like the `\qty` command of the `physics` package, you should just look into the definition of that command and adapt it to your needs. So open `physics.sty` and search for `\qty` (lines 35 to 63).

Comment: Well... I didn't though of doing that (but I just did), there's where I need help with. The `physics.sty` code is too advanced for me, I'd like to have help with that

Comment: It's not important. All I need is to be able to write `\grad(), \grad[]`, etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure where's the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{physics}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\grad}{s}{%
  \nabla
  \IfBooleanF{#1}{\qty}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
    \qty{x+y}, \qquad
    \qty(x+y), \qquad
    \qty[x+y], \qquad
    \qty{x+y}, \qquad
    \qty\Big(x)
\]

\begin{gather*}
    \grad{x+y} \qquad
    \grad(x+y) \qquad
    \grad[x+y] \qquad
    \grad|x+y|
\\
    \grad\Big(x+y) \qquad
    \grad\Big[x+y] \qquad
    \grad* \qquad
    \grad*x \qquad
    \grad*(x+y)
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This assuming that you really want to use `physics` with its weird syntax. I'd keep at arm's length from it.